# How to generate OAS yaml file from sources annotations using swagger 3.x?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, swagger-3.0, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I've spend hours on searching how to generate the OAS spec yaml file using swagger codegen in Java and I give up. I'd like to provide all API spec data within the Java source as a code annotations. It would be great to expose it via maven.

AFAIK I should use [swagger-codegen-maven-plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/3.0.0/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin), but I wasn't able to make it scan the source code to generate OAS yaml or JSON file.

I would appreciate a snippet of pom.xml with valid codegen plugin config.

Perhaps I should get back to the previous Swagger as this use case was handled straight forward in 2.x. Now i get frustrated of 3.x approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swagger Codegen generates code from an OpenAPI file. To do the opposite – generate an OpenAPI file from Java code annotations – you need [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/) e.g. its Maven plugin, [`swagger-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-maven-plugin).

Add following dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then utilise it in your build; example config:

```xml
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
           <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.9</version>
           <configuration>
               <outputFileName>openapi</outputFileName>
               <outputPath>${project.build.directory}/generatedtest</outputPath>
               <configurationFilePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/configurationFile.yaml</configurationFilePath>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>resolve</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

Comment: How can I use this in Gradle based project?